# Correct usage of the "--throttle" parameter of monkey?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, monkeyrunner, monkey

I could not set the interval between the generated events by `monkey`. [The official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) defines the usage of `--throttle` as **"Inserts a fixed delay between events. You can use this option to slow down the Monkey. If not specified, there is no delay and the events are generated as rapidly as possible."**

I need to generate **500 events** with a **1-second** interval between them.

Here is what I have used:

```
monkey -v --throttle 1000 -p com.estrongs.android.pop 500
```

So, the process should take at least **1000*500 milliseconds** which mean **more than 8 minutes**. But the job finishes in seconds.

Is there something I miss? How do you set the interval between events generated by `monkey` tool?

Answer (score 3):

`monkey` injects the specified delay after a *group of events*. You can specify only one type of events and time the command and the result will be as expected.

```
time monkey -v -v -v --throttle 2000 --pct-touch 100 -p  com.estrongs.android.pop 50
```

this will print some messages like

```
...
Sleeping for 2000 milliseconds
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(669.0,1746.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(658.455,1740.9874)
Sleeping for 2000 milliseconds
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(617.0,436.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(616.7584,433.1081)
Sleeping for 2000 milliseconds
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(529.0,1399.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(529.58325,1405.1238)
Sleeping for 2000 milliseconds
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(46.0,551.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(52.594234,557.6963)
Sleeping for 2000 milliseconds
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(1004.0,1706.0)
Events injected: 50
```

and then `time`:

```
0m50.30s real     0m00.20s user     0m00.04s system
```

which indicates the approx 50 secs expected (50*2000/2), 2 because it sends DOWN & UP.